# Pytorch: is there a function similar to torch.argmax which can really keep the dimension of the original data?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

For example, 
the code is

```
input = torch.randn(3, 10)
result = torch.argmax(input, dim=0, keepdim=True)
```

`input` is

```
tensor([[ 1.5742,  0.8183, -2.3005, -1.1650, -0.2451],
       [ 1.0553,  0.6021, -0.4938, -1.5379, -1.2054],
       [-0.1728,  0.8372, -1.9181, -0.9110,  0.2422]])
```

and `result` is

```
tensor([[ 0,  2,  1,  2,  2]])
```

However, I want a result like this

```
tensor([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  1,  0,  1,  1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I solved it. But this solution may not be efficient.
Code as follow,

```
input = torch.randn(3, 10)
result = torch.argmax(input, dim=0, keepdim=True)
result_0 = result == 0
result_1 = result == 1
result_2 = result == 2
result = torch.cat((result_0, result_1, result_2), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nn.functional.one_hot` and then permute for the axis you need, since one_hot expands the last dimension.

```
from torch.nn.functional import one_hot

input = torch.randn(3, 5)
output = one_hot(torch.argmax(input, dim=0)).permute(-1,0)
```

With input

```
tensor([[ 1.1320, -0.7152,  2.0861,  0.6044, -0.9840],
        [ 0.8313,  2.4974,  1.3477,  1.4260, -0.4859],
        [-0.6532,  2.5891, -1.3084,  2.0589,  1.8340]])
```

And output

```
tensor([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
```